# How to debug "Use of unresolved identifier" in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I'm learning about Xcode and using tutorials. I'm a beginner.

I'm looking at this code and have no clue why this is coming up with the following error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'USER_REF'

but in the code I'm pretty sure I reference the USER - is that right?

```
class DataService {

static let dataService = DataService()
fileprivate var _BASE_REF = Database.database().reference()
fileprivate var _USER_REF = Database.database().reference()
fileprivate var _USERPOST_REF = Database.database().reference()


var BASE_REF: DatabaseReference {
    return _BASE_REF
}

var USER_REF: DatabaseReference {
    return _USER_REF
}

var CURRENT_USER_REF: DatabaseReference {
    let userID = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "uid") as! String

    let currentUser = Database.database().reference().child(byAppendingPath: "user").child(byAppendingPath: userID)

    return currentUser
}

var USERPOST_REF: DatabaseReference {
    return _USERPOST_REF
}
}

func createNewAccount(uid: String, user: Dictionary<String, String>) {

    // A User is born?

    USER_REF.child(byAppendingPath: uid).setValue(user)
}

func createNewUserPost(userpost: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

    // Save the Post
    // USERPOST_REF is the parent of the new USERPOST: "userposts".
    // childByAutoId() saves the userpost and gives it its own ID.

    let firebaseNewUserPost = USERPOST_REF.childByAutoId()

    // setValue() saves to Firebase.

    firebaseNewUserPost?.setValue(userpost)
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with XCode, this question is about Swift code. Whether you are using the XCode IDE or not really has nothing to do with the question. You should note which line of this code is throwing the error you are getting.

Comment: First of all, this is Swift. Do not use private variables with leading underscores for backing instance variables to get  a constant. Just use the keyword `let`. And according to the naming convention variables and functions are supposed to start with a lowercase letter and be *camelCased* rather than *UPPER_SNAKE_CASED*. You should look for better tutorials. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect lesson in why indentation is important. There's a second `}` after the end of `USERPOST_REF: DatabaseReference`, which ends the scope of the `class DataService`.

As a result, `createNewAccount(uid:user:)` and `createNewUserPost(userpost:)` are standalone functions without access to any instance members of DatabaseReference.

A few points of improvement:

1. Swift convention for all properties, instance, class or static, is to use lowerCamelCase.
2. Unlike other languages (Java and Ruby are the main offenders here that I know of), there is no point making an instance variable with a public getter (computed property), such as `filprivate _x: Int`, with a `public var x: Int`. Namely, because `_x` ***is not an instance variable***. Swift doesn't actually let you make instance variables. They're generated for you when you create properties. What you're doing is writing a property that accesses a property you declared, to access an instance variable the compiler synthesized. There's no need for this. Just make the property's setter scoped to file private.
3. The conventional name of a singleton in Swift is `shared`, `default` or `main`. Try to stick with one of those. Additionally, in order for you to truly have a singleton, you need to restrict access to the initializer, by declaring it with `private` access.

Here is what I would recommend:

```
class DataService {
    static let shared = DataService()
    private init() {}

    public fileprivate(set) var baseDB = Database.database().reference()
    public fileprivate(set) var userDB = Database.database().reference()
    public fileprivate(set) var userPostDB = Database.database().reference()

    var currentUser: DatabaseReference {
        let userID = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "uid") as! String

        return Database.database()
            .reference()
            .child(byAppendingPath: "user")
            .child(byAppendingPath: userID)
    }


    func createNewAccount(uid: String, user: Dictionary<String, String>) {
        // A User is born?

        userDB.child(byAppendingPath: uid).setValue(user)
    }

    func createNewUserPost(userpost: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        // Save the Post
        // userPostDB is the parent of the new USERPOST: "userposts".
        // childByAutoId() saves the userpost and gives it its own ID.

        let firebaseNewUserPost = userPostDB.childByAutoId()

        // setValue() saves to Firebase.

        firebaseNewUserPost?.setValue(userpost)
    }
}
```

Comment: What an amazing thing an indentation can do to make things clearer!  Wow!  Thank you and lesson learned!

Comment: Actually *Swift convention for all properties, instance, class or static, is to use **lower**CamelCase*